# Remove negative numbers from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array coming from the database grabbing all the id's from a group of elements. However it seems to also be grabbing some negative id's from some backend stuff happening and it's breaking what I need to do with these id's.

Is there a way to remove these negative id's from the array before I loop it and put it in the app?

After I grab them I'm already looping through them.

```
ids.forEach(function(Id) {
            //Code adding elements matching with id's to the screen
});
```

I have tried adding an if statement in there to just not run that code if the id is less than 0, but that didn't seem to want to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `Array.filter`

```
ids = ids.filter(function(x){ return x > -1 });
```

Array.filter filters the elements based on the boolean returned. Here we filter only numbers which are greater than `-1`

Comment: I denied an edit suggesting to change `x > -1` to `x >= 0` since it's completely equal logically but it could be considered for readability.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've never actually used a filter before. New trick added to my book! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.filter with arrow function.

```
ids = ids.filter( x => x > -1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
ids = [-1,3,4,-2]
ids = jQuery.grep(ids, function( n, i ) {
  return n>=0;
});
console.log(ids)
```

Description: Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.